# R programming and sum up columns with different date column

Tags: r

Actually, i wanted to sum up by column  `Send_invites` and `MEMBER_RECEIVED_INVITES`
by `ID`, here I created from `DOI_DATE` adding 30 days to get Month1 then From Month1 adding another 30 days , getting Month2 etc upto 12 months

Now, I need to sum up as above by using `Date_created` column but the range of the date from `DOI_DATE` to `Month1` date sum up as Month 1 value

next date range from Month1 date to Month2 date in `Date_created` column sum up as month2 etc,  i need to sequence of ID's

Can anyone please help me with RCODE
Thank you

```
ID  COUNTRY_CODE    SEND_INVITES    MEMBER_RECEIVED_INVITES DOI_DATE1   DATE_CREATED1   Month1  Month2  Month3
1170309479  US  1   1   12/22/2016  1/14/2017   1/21/2017   2/20/2017   3/22/2017
1167268031  US  1   1   12/4/2016   1/6/2017    1/3/2017    2/2/2017    3/4/2017
1168417033  US  1   1   12/11/2016  1/6/2017    1/10/2017   2/9/2017    3/11/2017
1133456595  CA  1   1   10/31/2016  12/13/2016  11/30/2016  12/30/2016  1/29/2017
1026176359  CA  1   1   7/8/2016    9/20/2016   8/7/2016    9/6/2016    10/6/2016
1170285089  GB  1   1   12/23/2016  12/23/2016  1/22/2017   2/21/2017   3/23/2017
```

Comment: you should use dput() to make a reproducible example e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html

Comment: Can you please help us by showing your code (the code you have tried so far)?

Comment: SICI_1$DOI_DATE1<-as.POSIXct(as.Date(SICI_1$DOI_DATE))
 SICI_1$Month1<-as.Date(SICI_1$DOI_DATE1,format="%Y/%m/%d") + 30   ### added 30 days
 SICI_1$Month2<-as.Date(SICI_1$Month1,format="%Y/%m/%d") + 30
 SICI_1$Month3<-as.Date(SICI_1$Month2,format="%Y/%m/%d") + 30
 
this way i used to created the months, but i really do not know how to sum up send_invites column  by Id as well as by date at dated created column

Comment: in the continuation of above, i need to look the date range from Doi_date to Month1 date  to get the first month sum up